# Gnuplot_i date/time formatting error

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot_i library (version 2.11) in C -code which generates some png -pictures. However time/date column does not format correctly.

Source:

```
gnuplot_ctrl * h0 ;
h0 = gnuplot_init() ;
gnuplot_set_xlabel(h0, "Header") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set terminal png size 800,480") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set output 'picture.png'") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set xdata time") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M'") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set format x '%H:%M' ") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set grid") ;
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "plot \"datafile.tsv\" u 1:2 w l t \"Title\" ");
gnuplot_close(h0) ;
```

datafile.tsv contains:

```
2017-09-08-18:03    12.69

2017-09-08-18:04    12.69

2017-09-08-18:05    12.69

2017-09-08-18:06    12.69
```

...

Unfortunately command  `gnuplot_cmd(h0, "show timefmt");` produces error:

> Warning: empty x range `[1.48323e+09:1.48323e+09],` adjusting to
>   [1.4684e+09:1.49806e+09]  Default format for reading time data is
>   "%Y-No such file or directory-0- %H:%M"

Why %m get formatted "No such file or directory" and %d like "0" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read Gnuplot_i manual, and the command `gnuplot_cmd` has the parameter `cmd` that should be formatted like in the `printf` function. Your time format is interpreted as a format string because of the '%' characters. You should use instead something like

```
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set timefmt \"%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H:%%M\"");
gnuplot_cmd(h0, "set format x \"%%H:%%M\"") ;
```